# .Net Core ChallengeRequest not redirecting to the specified RedirectUri

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have a Rest API whose task is to authenticate the user to Azure AD. It uses a ChallengeRequest to login in as follows:

```
return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
            {  
                RedirectUri = "http://google.com"  
            }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

There are 2 terms to delineate here:

- **CallbackPath**: a parameter of the OpenIdConnect config. This URL must be authenticated in the list of 'Reply Urls' of the Identity Provider.
- **RedirectUri**: a property passed into the Challenge Request.

What I expect is that the request will redirect to the **RedirectUri** after authenticating against the OpenIdConnect scheme. The purpose being to redirect to a custom URL specified in a Query String. However it redirects to the **CallbackPath** instead.

---

UPDATE:

After tweaking the Azure AD settings in my answer below the scenario works as expected in Edge and Firefox browsers.

However this issue remains on the *Google Chrome* browser.

How do I get the request to redirect to the **RedirectUri**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out 3 settings needed to be configured on the Azure AD Application:

- Implicit Grant for Access Tokens
- Implicit Grant for ID Tokens
- "allowPublicClient": true

The answer for the issue on Chrome was investigated here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20347

Chrome has started requiring HTTPS for cookies like .AspNetCore.Correlation.OpenIdConnect that use SameSite=None

Answer (score 0):

That redirect url you set(in `AuthenticationProperties`) is to control which page/action should be redirect **after** authentication .

During authentication , the whole process is controlled by OpenID Connect middleware , after user validate credential in Azure's login page ,Azure Ad will redirect user back to your application's redirect url which is set in OIDC's configuration  , so that you can get the authorization code(if using code flow) and complete the authentication  process . **After** authentication , user will then be redirected to the redirect url (`google.com` as your codes) .

So if you want to change the callback url during the authentication , you should modify the OIDC's `CallbackPath` config .

Comment: Though you cannot set the CallbackPath to an absolute URL, only a relative URL. But it is the way it should be because if this app sent the user to authenticate, then it should be the one handling the result.

Comment: Thanks @NanYu, I expect it to return to the Callback URL followed by the AuthenticationProperties.RedirectUri URL, however it was not.

Comment: Could you please explain more about your current scenario ?

Comment: @NanYu I've added further description into the question as requested.